# Sandboxed solution - Pass datafrom client side(javascript) to server side

Tags: sandbox-solution

Can anyone suggest me with different ways to passing data from client side to server side?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use SPServices: http://spservices.codeplex.com/. This is javascript library based on jquery that allows you to communicate with Sharepoint through its web services.

Comment: But using the abpve how can we pass data from client to server?

Comment: You can update list items with this method for example http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems